# Creating vanilla tooltips/popups that reference other text, without scripts

Tags: html, css

I want to implement a tooltip on hover that references text earlier in a document.
E.g.

```
    1. blah blah blah
    2. more blah
    .
    . Hella blah
    .
    Way down somewhere in the page
    ... 

    "So as referenced in the first example ....."
```

I want to create a popoup or tooltip that shows the reader `<1. blah blah blah>` so
they don't have to scroll back up the page to get the info.

Most of the examples for creating tooltips presume that the text is in the tool tip.

Is it possible to implement a hover tooltip/popup in the way that I am thinking?

I thought maybe `<a href="#first">1. blah blah blah</a>` might be a code option but I'm not quite sure what is possible, or how to formulate the question for a web search.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at `aria-describedby` so you can build this with accessibility in mind.

> The aria-describedby attribute is not used only for form elements; it
>   is also used to associate static text with widgets, groups of
>   elements, panes, regions that have a heading, definitions, and more.

In addition, use `role="tooltip"`, since that's exactly what you're building.

```html
<span aria-describedby="tip1Text" role="tooltip"></span>
```

Elsewhere…

```html
<div class="visually-hidden" id="tip1Text">Tooltip text goes here.</div>
```

More excellent accessible tooltip examples can be found [here](http://accessibility.athena-ict.com/aria/examples/tooltip.shtml).

Comment: @KenIngram Sorry I missed that requirement. I don't see a way forward without a little scripting.

Comment: That's ok. I think it may not be possible. I deleted that comment.

Comment: The main problem is that the tooltip span apparently needs to be a sibling to the triggering element as well. The situation I have is that the tooltip text is already displayed earlier in the document. I don't want it hidden.